# How to verify if shortcut-app is internet accessible before loading it?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a shortcut/bookmark app that links to a website.
I want to execute some code, verifying if the website is up or if there is an internet connection before continuing to load the website while some ads are showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `navigator.onLine` property. http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/06/navigator-onLine-in-Chrome-Dev-channel-1

Comment: thanks, but what about, if there is internet conection, but the website is down or in maintenance? How to show the website even when is down?

Comment: Try using the AppCache features: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/